# file_get_contents()/curl getting unexpected page

Tags: php

I'm doing some scraping with php. I've been extracting data including link to the next relevant page so the whole thing is automatic. The problem is that I seem to be getting a page which is slightly modified compared to what I would expect using that URL in my browser (for e.g. the dates are different).

I've tried using curl and get_file_contents but both get the wrong file.

At the moment I am using:

```
$url = "http://www.example.com";

    $ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
url_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$temp = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

What is going on here?

UPDATE:

I've tried imitating a browser using the following code but still unsuccessful. I find this bizarre.

```
function get_url_contents($url){
$crl = curl_init();
$timeout = 10;
$header=array(
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026     Firefox/3.6.12',
 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
 'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5',
'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate',
'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
'Keep-Alive: 115',
'Connection: keep-alive',
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 

curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
$ret = curl_exec($crl);
curl_close($crl);
return $ret;
}
```

Further update:

Seems that the site is using my location to discriminate. Is there a locale option?

Comment: Try removing any cookies stored along for that domain in your browser, then load again and compare the result to your curl result.

Comment: Nope, browser still gets the desired page.

Answer (score 2):

Can be many things...

1. Server may render pages differently based on cookies and header sent
2. Server may render pages differently based on existing pre-conditions and states on the server
3. You may have a proxy in between that modifies the content based on user-agent and since you don't have a specific user-agent (such as CURL browser) then your proxy is sending back different content

This is just a few things that could happen!

Comment: Ah ok. Are there any parameters which I can pass to curl to imitate my browser?

Comment: You can use `curl_setopt()` to set a custom user agent identifier: `curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Any user agent string you like');`